# Как добавить плавность по кликам на вкладки через JS?

Tags: javascript

Есть список из Li Элементов, клик по которым должен менять картинку в соответствии с выбранным li
Вопрос в том как добиться плавности в смене картинок
Код на codepen: https://codepen.io/kurday/pen/YzwNedL

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function (e){
  e.preventDefault();
  const target = e.target;

  //в Make забиваем элемент по которому произошел клик (li)
  const make = target.closest('.nav-item'); //make = this.li

  if (make) {
    //в img записываем класс ссылки которая внутри этого li
    img = make.querySelector('.nav-link'); // img = li a

    //В changeImg записываем dataset этой ссылки
    const changeImg = img.dataset.src; //changeImg = data a

    //подставляем изображение 
    if (changeImg) {
      featuredImage.src = changeImg
    }
  }
```

Comment: что здесь имеется ввиду поп плавностью?

Comment: Плавное появление картинки.